# Using "!" on contains

Tags: swift, boolean

Given this code:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let b = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

let result = a.filter(b.contains)

print(result) // [5]
```

But what if I want `let result = a.filter { !b.contains($0) }`? How can I do it the same way as the example above?

```
let result = a.filter { !b.contains($0) } // works
let result = a.filter(!b.contains)        // fails
```

Comment: What you are expecting as the answer given that you already found a method that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a custom operator.

```
prefix func !<T>(_ predicate: @escaping (T) -> Bool) -> (T) -> Bool {
    return { element in
        return !predicate(element)
    }
}
```

and then `a.filter(!b.contains)` will work.

Or if that feels like operator overloading abuse, then you could just extend `Sequence` and use it as `a.filter(b.not(b.contains))` but it's kind of ugly:

```
extension Sequence {
    func not(_ predicate: @escaping (Self.Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> (Self.Iterator.Element) -> Bool {
        return { element in
            return !predicate(element)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let result = a.filter { !b.contains($0) }
```

This is syntactic sugar for:

```
let result = a.filter({ !b.contains($0) })
```

`filter` takes a function value. `{...}` is a literal function value (a "closure"), just like `1` is a literal `Int` value. So that's fine. Inside the closure, you apply the `!` prefix operator to the result of `b.contains($0)`. That's also fine.

```
let result = a.filter(!b.contains)        // fails
```

Again, `filter` takes a function value. `b.contains` is a function value, so that part is fine, which is why `a.filter(b.contains)` works. But the `!` prefix operator can't be applied to a function value, so that fails.

Anurag demonstrates how you would write an implementation of `!` that does take a function and return a function, which works, but would be confusing IMO because this is not a standard use of that operator, and these kinds of operator overloads tend to slow down the compiler (sometimes dramatically, because it has to chase more type possibilities). While there are various ways you might try to "make this work," the best Swift here would generally be the closure syntax because it's clear and standard.

That said, a reasonable approach if you were doing this kind of thing a lot, would be to create a `not` function that takes a function and returns a function, like Anurag's `!`, but without overloading the operator:

```
func not<T>(_ predicate: @escaping (T) -> Bool) -> (T) -> Bool {
    return { !predicate($0) }
}
```

Then you could call `a.filter(not(b.contains))`. But again, I'd probably only do that if building up complex functions were an important part of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and explanation. Helps so much and afaik, it's not mentioned often (if at all) in the books I've read. Still marked Anurag's answer since it did what I wanted. Much appreciated!